# Shiv'a Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The age of our foremother Sarah when she died. (Genesis 23:1.)

Comment: And there's some medrish about the merit of Sarah ... that her descendant Esther would reign over 127 states; something like that?  Can anyone help here?

Comment: It's R' Akiva trying to excite his students. See בראשית רבה נח:ג - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9658&st=&pgnum=480

Answer (score 7):

Sheva v'esrim umeya medinah.  ("Medinah" is feminine, hence "sheva" not "shiv'a.")

127 were the states governed by King Ahasueros (Esther 1:1)

Isn't there an English book called "127" with 127 thoughts on Purim out there?

Answer (score 4):

According to the opinion that Avraham recognized Hashem at age 48 (Bereishis Rabbah 95:3), he served Hashem for 127 years (175 minus 48).

Answer (score 3):

127 years ago (July 1883) was the "Treifa Banquet" instigating the split between Conservative and Reform doctrines.

Comment: must be some symbolic connection to Ahasueros' party